# Sort double array according to specific order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I am trying to sort an array to specific order, for an example: I want to sort the array `map` as `[2, 0, 1, 2]` according to the order or `arr`. But I am getting errors.

```
double[] arr = {3, 1.3, 2, 3};
int[] map = {0, 1, 2, 3};
// I want to get [2, 0, 1, 2]
Collections.sort(map, (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

This is only a pseudo code and I am aware that it does not work. How can this be achieved without using double loops?

Edit
The result array `[2,0,1,2]` should be calculated as the rank of the numbers in arr. 1.3 is the least, so it gets rank 0. 2 gets rank 1, and both 3 gets rank 2.

Comment: Can you explain the logic here? Where did the second 2 come from? Where did the 3 go? How does this relate to `arr`?

Comment: Basically, you're going to need to explain in more detail how you're getting that sequence from what you've shown. Assuming you meant "order *of* array", I'd expect it to be something like `1, 2, 0, 3` (ie, those numbers are the array indexes of the values in `arr` in sorted order).

Comment: where are `;`? is it a pseudocode? you are getting errors, because everything you wrote is wrong

Comment: What he means is: 1.3 is "zeroth", 2 is "first", 3 is "2nd" so -> 2, 0, 1, 2

Comment: `Collections.sort` has the return type `void`. It cannot be the RHS of an assignment. Furthermore you cannot a variable you declare on the RHS of an assignment.

Comment: What you seem to be asking is to produce the rank of the elements of arr[] in map. One way to do this is to create yet another array of Integer indices 0 to n-1 and use a lambda compare to sort the array of indices according to arr. This will result in something like indices[] = {1,2,0,3}. Then to generate a rank, for i = 0 to n-1 ... map[indices[i]] = i;, resulting in map[] = {2,0,1,3}.

Comment: That is only pseudo code. The second 2 comes at the last because both 3's (first and last) have the same rank.

Comment: Collections take objects as parameters and it can't take primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

This works (although it is a very inelegant solution), it doesn't use double for-loops but I'm guessing you're looking for an elegant solution.

```
public class IntegerOrderMapper {

    public int[] map(int[] input) {
        int[] output = new int[input.length];
        int[] sorted = input.clone(); // 3, 1.3, 2, 3
        Arrays.sort(sorted); // 1.3, 2, 3, 3

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) { // removes duplicates
            set.add(sorted[i]); // 1.3, 2, 3
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            output[i] = Arrays.asList(set.toArray()).indexOf(input[i]);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class IntegerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntegerOrderMapper iom = new IntegerOrderMapper();
        int[] result = iom.map(new int[] {3, 1, 2, 3}); // <- using integers here

        for(int i : result) {
            System.out.println(i); // <- prints 2, 0, 1, 2
        }
    }
}
```

This version works only with an integer array but you could create a generic version to work with any object.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for efficiency of the `findRank()` code, don't call `list.indexOf()` multiple times in loop. The time complexity of finding element in a list is O(n). For O(1) complexity, use `Map` instead of a `List`. I assume you can easily replace `List` with `Map` implementation.

Comment: In algortihm complexity theory, finding the rank of an element in an *unsorted* array takes O(n). So it is mathematically proven that you can't find the rank any faster... even if you change the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted the array in java8 with following code

```
double[] da = {99, 11, 7, 21, 4, 2};
da = Arrays.stream(da)
    .boxed()
    .sorted((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)) //using comparator
    .mapToDouble(i -> i)
    .toArray();
```

I actually wanted to find the rank of each item after sorting the array. so I found that out with following function.

```
private static int[] findRank(double[] x){
    //declare empty list and rank array
    List<Double> lst = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int[] rank=new int[x.length]; // maximum length for already unique array
    //add only unique elements of x in the list
    for(double d:x)
        if (lst.indexOf(d) == -1)
            lst.add(d);

    Collections.sort(lst);
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        rank[i]=lst.indexOf(x[i]);
    }
    return rank;
}
```

What I am interested in is better implementation of above code. Especially the loop part.